# Problemas com Ckeditor

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

Estou com um probleminha no Ckeditor, estou instanciando na minha pagina o link para acesso do código principal do ckeditor e colocando nos meus campos os ids respectivos, já transferi a pasta ck editor para meu servidor, só que o campo de edição não aparece na tela. segue parte do meu código:

```
<html>
```

This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            
            
                // Replace the  with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor3' );

Comment: <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.dpaulatreinamentos.com/system/teste03/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea name="Lousa" id="editor3" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor3' );
            </script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Olá William De Paula, acredito que seja alguma incompatibilidade com outra biblioteca pois postei no meu servidor o seu html (veja no código fonte) e está funcionando a contento, pode verificar em http://kithomepage.com/sos/Problemas-com-Ckeditor.htm

Comment: Você não está publicando esse html e o script em uma única linha não né? Que outras bibliotecas usa em sua página?